# First row records is missing when we export the csv using ng-table-export (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, csv, ngtable

I'm using [ng-table-export](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table-export) in my project . when i export First row records is missing. I have attached a screen short and my coding , kindly guide me .

UI output 
[image]

Exported CSV 
[image]

My coding in tpl

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-mousedown="csv.generate()" ng-href="{{ csv.link() }}" download="test.csv">Export to CSV</a>
```

Comment: Can you share the code detail?

Comment: The UI and the exported data do not seem to match. Is that an issue or just for display purpose you simply took two instances?

Comment: Thank  you for your comment paje007 ., It's the issue not for just display .

Comment: Anil singh i'm using ng-table-export module (https://github.com/esvit/ng-table-export)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issues by changing ng-table-export module to [ngCSV](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv) .

Answer (score 0):

In  ng-table-export there is a function parseTable()
For some reason, a condition is given to exclude index 1

```
//if (i !== 1) {
    angular.forEach(tds, function(td) {
    // respect colspan in row data
    rowData += stringify(angular.element(td).text()) + Array.apply(null, Array(td.colSpan)).map(function () { return delimiter; }).join('');
                });
    rowData = rowData.slice(0, rowData.length - 1); //remove last semicolon
 //}
```

If you comment it out, It will work fine.